# In a service mesh architecture the call from service A to service B must happen through a central component?

Tags: kubernetes, architecture, servicemesh

Let's say we have the following setup:

- **Service A** consists of a pod in a Kubernetes cluster with two containers **Api A** and **Sidecar A**. **Api A** communicates with the outside world through **Sidecar A**. **Sidecar A** is registered as a consumer.
- **Service B**  consists of a pod in a Kubernetes cluster with two containers **Api B** and **Sidecar B**. **Api B** communicates with the outside world via **Sidecar B**. **Sidecar B** is registered as a producer.

**Service A** and **Service B** could potentially have multiple instances.

The services register themselves with the service mesh through a central authority, let's call it *Service Discovery*, that knows about the specific instances of each service and the endpoints that they expose. **Service A** can also subscribe to a specific endpoint of **Service B** via this *Service Discovery* central authority. (The central authority also deals with security, tokens and certificates but I want to simplify)

**Sidecar A** and **Sidecar B** regularly communicate with *Service Discovery* to confirm availability.

How should **Service A** call an endpoint of **Service B**:

- directly via a specific url because the **Sidecar A** should know about the instances of **Service B** via service discovery and should choose a healthy one?
- or indirectly by calling a generic api of *Service Discovery* which should know what are the healthy instances that can be called and redirect the request to one of them accordingly?
- or in some other way?

Comment: Please provide more information about your current setup - which Kubernetes version are you using, which solution did you use to setup a cluster (kubeadm or some cloud provider solution etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the recommended way is for service A to call endpoint B directly via a specific URL because the Sidecar A should know about the instances of Service B via service discovery and should choose a healthy instance.
The purpose of service discovery is just that: to allow services to be discoverable. It should not serve as a proxy between calls.